# Cómo contar los registros únicos contarlos y agruparlos

Tags: sql, tsql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta donde me busque todos los registros únicos `telefono_busqueda` de la tabla `Clientes`, me los agrupe y los cuente.

Lo que busco:

Totalizar la cantidad exacta de `cliente_plan` pero en la tabla hay registros duplicados el `id` de cada registro es `telefono_busqueda` por eso estoy tratando de aplicarle un `distinct` al campo `telefono_busqueda` para que no me traiga los duplicados.

```sql
select cliente.cliente_plan, count(cliente.cliente_plan) as Cantidad
from dbo.clientes as cliente
where (select distinct cliente.telefono_busqueda from dbo.Clientes)
group by cliente_plan
order by (Cantidad) desc;
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'select'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near
> ')'.

Comment: ¿Necesitas saber cuantas veces esta un `telefono_busqueda` en la tabla? ¿Que tiene que ver `cliente_plan`? ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta, agregar un ejemplo de los datos que tenes y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Totalizar la cantiad de `cliente_plan` pero aplicandole un filtro a la busqueda. Un `distinct` al campo `telefono_busqueda` para no traerme los registros duplicados

Comment: ¿Se puede dar que un `telefono_busqueda` pertenezca a más de un `cliente_plan`? En caso afirmativo ¿podes determinar cual es el último?

Comment: No, un número de teléfono sólo puede tener asociado un único plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si buscas las cantidad de `cliente_plan` distintos, no es necesario agrupar:

```
select  count(distinct cliente.cliente_plan) as Cantidad
        from dbo.clientes as cliente
```

Y si quieres conocer la cantidad de `telefono_busqueda` por cada `cliente_plan` entonces si agrupas:

```
select  cliente.cliente_plan, 
        count(distinct cliente.telefono_busqueda)  as Cantidad
        from dbo.clientes as cliente
        group by cliente_plan
        order by (Cantidad) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

en realidad ese sub select es el incorrecto, debería ser así

```
select distinct telefono_busqueda
       count(cliente_plan) as 'Cantidad'
from dbo.Clientes
group by cliente_plan
ORDER BY count(cliente_plan) DESC;
```